# Is it optimal to run AsyncTask (that retrieve data from an API) in the fragment or in the activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer activity and i want to retrieve data from an API using AsyncTask.
I will then filter and categorize this data based on the selection from the navigation drawer.
Should i call the AsyncTask from the activity itself or from the home fragment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: none of them, activities and fragments are responsible only for views.

Comment: it depends on which architecture pattern you follow. if its MVC pattern, its good to fetch data in activity than fragment. Other patterns, say, MVVM, data is fetched from viewmodel.

Comment: so you are saying i should call the asynctask from an outside class,and return the data as an object to either of them?

Comment: I would do it in the `Activity`. Fragments can get unloaded and recreated by Android and the `Activity` is more stable. IMHO this is a better architecture. However, the actual work gets done in a background thread anyway, so from a performance standpoint it is completely irrelevant.